# VBA to return value from dynamic range (w. addition of new column)

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I have a range C7:AD7 in workbook1 where C7:AC7 are random numbers and AD7 is the SUM of all those numbers. However, the SUM column shifts to the right after the user inserts a new column and enters a new random number. I have another workbook2 where I'd like to link to the SUM column and have the link automatically adjust as the workbook1 SUM columns moves to the right.

Can someone help me with this? Either VBA or through a formula?

Thanks
Jake

Answer (score 1):

Give the cell a range-name (a defined name). Click in the sum's cell and go to the Formulas tab (Excel 2007/2010), Defined Names group and click **Define Name**. Type a name (without spaces) and click OK.

Open both books, begin a formula in the other book with '=', click to the other book and click on your named-cell. Excel will use the defined-name in the formula.

The defined-name will move with the cell, when a column is inserted.